# Deploy EF code first using Azure Pipelines

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework code first. I am able to update my database during development using Update-Database from Nuget Package Manager. Now I want to the database to be updated when building from my Azure Pipeline. Is there any documentation from Microsoft of this? How are others handling this?

Answer (score 0):

*(Not sure how much information you are looking for, so ask a follow-up/add a comment if this isn't enough.)*

Server-side (e.g. in CI pipelines) as well as client-side, this can be done with the CLI instead of the VS specific package manager console:

```
dotnet ef database update --verbose
```

See [Entity Framework Core tools reference - .NET Core CLI: dotnet ef database update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-database-update) for further information.

---

Generally, I would discourage anybody from automatically applying database migrations to a production environment.

Migrations should always be scripted to a file via [dotnet ef migrations script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-migrations-script), thoroughly checked and tested and only then be applied directly from this script (after creating a backup) to a production database.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I want to use a script file and I agree with your statement about validating the script file prior to migration into the database. We are planning on using the pipeline approval method to introduce a manual approval process prior to implementing the change. 
I just wanted to see how others are doing this. I am new to pipelines and was reading over [this Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/azure-sqldb?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), but I didn't like the idea of my pipeline messing with the firewall.